# Widgets broken on KDE Plasma 5.24 Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu

Adding any widget to the panel is fruitless.  The widget fails to appear.

The process that I use is to right click on the panel at the bottom of the KDE Window.  Select +Add Widget,  select a Widget. "Activity Pager"

There is not activity pager displayed on the panel.  I like to have four desktops.  So what is the secret to having multiple desktops on KDE 5.24?

```
Operating System: Kbuntu 22.04 LTS
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.16.0-051600rc8-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16× AMD Ryzen 7 4800U with Radeon Graphics
Memory: 2.1 GiB used 30.8 Gib Total of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD RENOIR
```

---

Thankyou Mook  Yes.  I did that.  It resulted in yet another instance of the invisible widget.  Which I am unabel to use.  I can remove invisible widgets.  But they never appear on the panel.  The file in my directory shows they are there.

grep pager  ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
plugin=org.kde.plasma.pager
plugin=org.kde.plasma.activitypager

Comment: ahh, widgets broken too.
this is not a single bug in 22.04
I am in disaster,
I created theme with other 22.04 kde issues.
maybe any will listen...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422306/widgets-broken-on-kde-plasma-5-24-kubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity Pager`-widget will become visible as soon as you have more than one activitiy configured. With only one activity left the widget is only visible in edit mode.

Go to `System Settings`>`Workspace Behavior`>`Activities` and create a new activity:

[image]

If you want to use virtual desktops instead of activities, use the `Pager`-widget instead and add a second virtual desktop similar as described above.